# visual studio tools for git wrong publish reset

Tags: git

I'm using Visual Studio tools for git and accidentally input the wrong publish information https://github.com/fredreload/TestGit.git for github repository. How do I change this publish information, undo "add solution to source control" does not reset it either. I have to create a new project in order to input the correct publish information and upload it to the github repository. What if I want to change the github directory from TestGit to TestProject, is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Visual Studio tools, but if you want to change the remote origin you can open `git-bash`, navigate to the directory and execute the following command.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/fredreload/TestProject.git
```